# Accessing outer part of nested dictionary in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to figure out a way to output the names of the data (ANKS6, FAM209A, etc.) should they meet the if statement requirements. Then store them in a list.

```
deg_data = {'ANKS6': {'log2FC': 3, `'BH_pvalue': 0.471732086999999},`
'FAM209A': {'log2FC': 2, 'BH_pvalue': 0.3464524916}}
for x in deg_data: 
if deg_data[x]['log2FC']>=2 and deg_data[x]['BH_pvalue']<=0.05:
print(deg_data[x].keys())
```

of course `print(deg_data[x].keys())` doesn't return the data names for the dictionary outside the nested one.

Comment: Check your `x` variable, it appears to contain what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe it was so simple

Comment: You can use this more explicit code which will also have `x` contain your dictionary keys: `for x in deg_data.keys():`

Answer (score 0):

<=0.05You can do it using a list comprehension:

```
deg_data = {'ANKS6': {'log2FC': 3, 'BH_pvalue': 0.471732086999999},
            'FAM209A': {'log2FC': 2, 'BH_pvalue': 0.3464524916}}
your_keys = [key for key, value in deg_data.items() if value['log2FC'] >= 2 and value['BH_pvalue'] <= 0.5]
print(your_keys)  # ['ANKS6', 'FAM209A']
```